# When deploying a Laravel Octane app with Swoole on Kubernetes (or AWS ECS), is a separate Nginx container required alongside the Octane app?

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, nginx, swoole, laravel-octane

In the context of Kubernetes (or AWS ECS), when deploying a Laravel Octane application using Swoole (or RoadRunner), is it essential to include a separate Nginx container (or any other web server) alongside the Octane app container?

Given that Laravel Octane utilizes Swoole (or RoadRunner) as a built-in web server, does the presence of Nginx remain necessary? Can the Octane app be directly exposed on port 80 to receive requests from a load balancer, such as the AWS Load Balancer, without needing an additional web server like Nginx?

Comment: unless you can map the actual domain name and configure SSL from octane , then you pretty much need a  web server that can handle those, same reason why a lot NodeJS folks still use NGINX to deploy in production

Comment: In our production environment we use AWS load balancer to map the domain and SSL. The load balancer redirects the requests to the AWS ECS on port 80. We use two container, one for nginx and the other one for the application. But I think the nginx is not necessary in this case. Am I forgetting some import stuff that nginx do?

Comment: whats your nginx config look like? why no forward your load balancer directly to your octane port?

Comment: @silver that is the question! Why not? The nginx config file just creates a proxy to octane port.

Comment: try it, otherwise post your nginx config